# expanding variadic template parameter pack in using expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a set of classes like

```
class A { void Do(int&); }
class B { void Do(char&); }
some more...
```

Is it possible to connect these classes by a variadic template like this:

```
template <typename ...T>
class ConnectIt: public T...
{
    using T ...::Do; // this expression fails.
                     // Some hints to get a set of using 
                     // expressions from parameter pack?
};
```

Instantiate with something like:

```
Class MyOne: public ConnectIt<A,B> {} my;
int i;
char c;    

my.Do(i);
my.Do(c);
```